# Conditional probability vs compound event probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A triangular region in a city is contaminated by a chemical industry. 2% of the children live in this triangle. 14% of these test positive for excessive toxic metals present in tissues. The rate of positive tests for children in the city not living in the triangle is only 1%.

I am trying to put the above information into  probabilities. They look like below:

T being living in triangle, P being tested positive,T' being not living in triangle.

**P(T)=0.02, P(PT)=0.14, P(PT')=0.01, P(T')=0.98**

However the solution puts it as **P(P/T)=0.14** and **P(P/T')=0.01**. Why is this written in terms of conditional probability and not as compound event ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it says that 14% of children in the triangle test positively, it means: if you draw a random child from the triangle, it will have a 14% chance of testing positive. This is $\mathbb P (P \mid T)$.

The interpretation of $\mathbb P (P \cap T)$ is the probability that a random person from the whole population is both in the triangle and tests positively. Do you see the difference?

Comment: Yes !. This makes sense. I could not figure out that they were drawing a person from the triangle. Just out of curiosity, how would the problem statement for ℙ(P∩T) look like ?

Comment: @lets_try it's just "what's the probability that a child is in the triangle and tests positive"

Answer (score 0):

The formula of conditional probability is: $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)} \Rightarrow P(A\cap B)=P(B)\cdot P(A|B).$

Here is the probability tree diagram of the problem:
[image]

Thus:

$P(P|T)=P$(positive, given that a random child has been selected from the triangular region);

$P(T\cap P)=P$(a randomly selected child from the city is both from the triangular region and positive).

Comment: The  probability tree is an overkill but kudos to your effort. Thank you ! :)

Comment: You are welcome.